# store math operation in a angularjs variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []); 

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http){
 $scope.plusvalenza1='';
 $scope.budget0=60;
 $scope.plusvalenza= function(venduto,acquistato){return venduto - acquistato};
 $http.get("rosa.php").success(function(data){
  $scope.rose=data;
 });
 
    $http.get("giocatoriLiberi.php").success(function(data){
  $scope.giocLiberi=data;
 }); 
 
 $scope.range = function(start, end) {
    var result = [];
    start = parseInt(start); //Make string input int
    end = parseInt(end);
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
};
```

```html
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">

<div class="row"> 
   
    <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Vendere:</label> 
              <select ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-options="(rosa.nome+' '+rosa.costo) for rosa in rose"></select>

       </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Acquistare:</label>
              <select ng-model="giocAcq1" ng-options="(lib.nome+' '+lib.costo) for lib in giocLiberi | filter:{ruolo:selectedItem1.ruolo}"></select>

    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-1">

              <label>Offerta:</label>
              <select ng-model="off0" style="width: 60px" ng-options="page for page in range(giocAcq1.costo, budget0--selectedItem1.costo)" ></select>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label></label>
        <div ng-model="budget0">Il tuo budget e': {{budget0}} fantamilioni</div> 
     <p ng-model="plusvalenza1" ng-show="selectedItem1.costo > giocAcq1.costo">Questa offerta ti garantisce una plusvalenza di {{plusvalenza(selectedItem1.costo,giocAcq1.costo)}} fantamilioni per la prossima busta</p>
    </div>
    

 
</div>
</div>
```

in the attached code i'd like to store the result of the plusvalenza(selectedItem1.costo,giocAcq1.costo) function in the ng-model="plusvalenza1" or in any way in a variable thath i can  after use in a post service to send data at my db.

I tried like a select tag but i have not the same result...can anyone help me?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save the result in the scope before returning it?
Like this:

```
$scope.plusvalenzaResult = 0;
$scope.budget0 = 60;
$scope.plusvalenza = function(venduto, acquistato) {
   $scope.plusvalenzaResult = venduto - acquistato;
    return $scope.plusvalenzaResult;
    //or you can just reference this variable in html instead of returning it
};
```

Comment: ok thanls, but i have two questions: 1. in this way can i pass plusvalenzaResult to a post service? 2. what happens if I want to pass more than one plusvalenzaResult as result of plusvalenza function? i.e. plusvalenzaResult1=plusvalenza(venduto1,acquistato1) and plusvalenzaResult2=plusvalenza(venduto2,acquistato2)?

Comment: 1. yes, the post would be  $http.post("giocatoriLiberi.php", {myData : $scope.plusvalenzaResult })
2. for multiple results, I would use an array and push the results in array and then use the array when posting to the server

Comment: ok thanks a lot...i will try use the array...hope I will not bothering you again :D